# Copy Result from SQL to Excel as Text without Formatting

Tags: sql, excel

I have SQL result as below:

[image]

When I copy and paste into Excel, it automatically convert to date.

[image]

I need to change the column format to Text before paste the value in order to have as extracted from SQL.
I have try to convert in SQL but still giving the same output in excel.

SELECT convert(nvarchar,test) test from tableXXX

Also try to save SQL result as csv.

How can I get the value as in SQL without formatting it in excel?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Paste Options within Excel and click: **Use Text Import Wizard**

On Step 3, you'll be able to choose "text" as your column data format.

[image]

Comment: But everytime I need to do this in excel? Can it be automatically converted to text? Like convert from SQL?

Comment: no because Excel automatically tries to interpret the format from the source